# How can I copy an ACF field to AIOSEO field?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to update and modify the accepted answer to this question [Copy SEO Meta Desc "Custom Field" to Excerpt field?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70990/copy-seo-meta-desc-custom-field-to-excerpt-field) to use an ACF custom field and different "if" logic.

I want to check if the post has an ACF field called `body`; and if it does, then check to see if there is an existing `_aioseop_description` field for the post; if that is empty, write the `$add_description` to the `_aioseop_description` field.

But this doesn't work on plugin activation, and there are no errors in the debug.log.

Is my "if" logic correct?

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_activation_run' );

function wpse_activation_run()
{   
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'published',
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $body = get_field('body');

    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {

        if (!empty($body) )

        {

            $add_description = get_field('body'); substr($add_description, 0, 150);

            $aioseop = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_aioseop_description' ,true);

                if (empty($aioseop) )
{

                $po['_aioseop_description'] = $add_description;
                wp_update_post($po);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Update:** this works and is more of a "big hammer" approach as it doesn't do any checking as to if the `_aioseop_description` field is already populated or the ACF field exists; and this will overwrite the `_aioseop_description` field on every activation. This will work for a `post` and an ACF field called `body`. It also trims the output and strips html with `wp_trim_words`, and uses `update_post_meta` instead of updating the entire post.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse_activation_run' );

function wpse_activation_run()
{   
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'   => 'post',
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'post_status' => 'published',
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $posts as $post )

    {

    $add_description = get_field('body', $post->ID); 

    $trimmed = wp_trim_words( $add_description, $num_words = 20,'' );

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_aioseop_description', $trimmed );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things I noticed: `get_field()` isn't specifying a post to get the field from, which is necessary outside the loop:

```
$add_description = get_field( 'body', $post->ID );`
```

And to set a post meta value you should use `update_post_meta()`, not `wp_update_post()`:

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_aioseop_description', $add_description );
```

Comment: Thanks! Good points, and I can see why, but they don't make a difference. And still no errors in the log. And I removed the $body = get_field('body'); below get_posts in case that was being overwritten.

Comment: Did you also remove the `if (!empty($body) )`?

Comment: Ah, the if (!empty($body) ) seemed to be it; I guess that needs the $post->ID. So it works now, though I do want to include that condition to make it more efficient. I also found that the resulting descriptions contained html, so used wp_trim_words to strip those. Now I need to either overwrite all the descriptions that have html, or clean the descriptions in the database and run the plugin again.

Comment: Well the problem was that you were checking it before the loop, so it wasn't doing anything. You should be checking the value of `$add_description` instead, after you set it.

Comment: That makes sense...